# how to set margin for PrintLayout in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

i have a javaFx application and am working on the Printer module , in the software am done with other things, like installed printer list , taking print from the specific printer but getting issue in the layout , now am having 80mm printer and when i get print from this printer then there are lots of margin in left side and right side, please help me to get correct print.

am using following code for print:-

```
PageLayout pageLayout = prnterForJob.createPageLayout(Paper.MONARCH_ENVELOPE,
                        PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(prnterForJob);
            job.getJobSettings().setCopies(nmbrOfCopies1);
            if (job != null) {
                //boolean success = job.printPage(node);
                weOrderPrint.print(job);
                job.endJob();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just forgetting to set the page layout you created?

```
job.getJobSettings().setPageLayout(pageLayout);
```

Comment: yes ... now i added .. but layout not comes at centre .. it comes on right side ... how i get it at centre?

Comment: Well, hard for me to troubleshoot without access to your printer, etc. I would experiment with different settings for the margins.

Comment: thanks ... i found supported paper form printer ... now every thing is fine.